# x509 certificate key to asymmetric algorithm

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate, encryption-asymmetric

Re-doing this question since I don't know if I was getting my point across correctly.

I have a signedXML object

```
Dim signedXml As New SignedXml(envelope)
```

I need to set the SigningKey property of this object

```
signedXml.SigningKey
```

I also have my certificate object

```
Dim cert As X509Certificate = Me.GetX509Certificate
```

How can I set the SigningKey property of signedXml using my cert.

In .NET 2.0 each X509Certificate had a 'Key' property which returned an RSA object, but in 3.5 this property is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use `X509Certificate2` and its `PrivateKey` property instead.